# Phaser js - How to mute sounds?

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I am attempting to mute all sounds on my Phaser JS project,  however using the below doesn't work.

```
game.sound.mute
```

What is the best way to mute all sounds on a Phaser.js project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
game.sound.mute = true;
```

I've just checked and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my game, I only have one sound that plays when you swipe the screen, so I just made a variable (soundOn) and added an if statement to play the sound in the function that is called when input is lifted off the screen.  You can just have a switch in the settings menu to switch the soundOn variable like I did.

Comment: I'm giving an example of how I muted "all" sounds in my game so of course it answers the question.  To build on to my answer, you could just put all instances of sound being played in an if statement having the argument being a boolean value of sound being on or off.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Another thing that works too is after the you create a end function use "sound.kill" and boom!! No more sound.

this.game.add.button(0,100,”ending”, this);

```
ending:function()
{ 
This.song.kill;//by doing this it’ll be reusable later
},
```

Orrr simply

this.game.song.destroy();

I think it’ll be better to destroy it it all depends how you use the song. Then again just a simple mute works too. It’s just some options